# CSS Custom shape is not scalable

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I created 4-star shape with CSS. Now I want it to be resizable relative to screen size. Everything else on my page is responsive to screen size, except this one shape.
Here's the code for it

```
#vert    {    
    position: relative;    
    border-bottom: 18em solid @444;    
    border-left: 16em solid transparent;    
    border-right: 16em solid transparent;    
    top: -7rem;   
    content: "";    

}

#vert::after    
{    
    position: absolute;    
    border-top: 18em solid #444;    
    border-left: 16em solid transparent;    
    border-right: 16em solid transparent;    
   bottom: -32rem;    
   left: -16rem;     
    content: "";    

}

#hori    
{
    position: absolute;    
    border-left: 19em solid #444;    
    border-top: 12em solid transparent;    
    border-bottom: 12em solid transparent;    
    top: -3rem    
    right: -3rem;    
    content: "";     

}
#hori::before    
{    
    position: absolute;    
    border-right: 19em solid #444;    
    border-top: 12em solid transparent;    
    border-bottom: 12em solid transparent;    
    top: -12rem;    
    left: -38rem;    
    content: "";    

}
```

I tried with different units from rem to px but its still not scaling down, or up. On smaller widths it fills up the whole viewport. Is there a possible way to make it resizeable?

Comment: Could you make your code into a working snippet? When I run what you have given with my best guess at the HTML structure it comes out not as a star. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example If you want to be sure of the shape staying within the viewport consider using vmin units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use vw

```css
#vert    {    
    position: relative;    
    border-bottom: 10vw solid #444;    
    border-left: 34vw solid transparent;    
    border-right: 34vw solid transparent;    
    top: 5vw;  
    content: "";    

}

#vert::after    
{    
    position: absolute;    
    border-top: 10vw solid #444;    
    border-left: 20vw solid transparent;    
    border-right: 20vw solid transparent;    
    bottom: -25vw;    
    left: -7vw;     
    content: "";    

}
```

```html
<body>
<div id='vert'></div>
</body>
```